# Оператор == ?

Tags: операторы, c++

Как определить оператор ==() в классе ?

Comment: Попробуйте [Гугл](http://www.google.com/search?q=operator+overloading+c%2B%2B) или книгу по C++ (любую). Это базовая часть языка.

Answer (score 3):

```
class element
{
    ...
    SomeType value;
    public:
    ...
    friend bool operator==(const element& left, const element& right);   
}
...
bool operator==(const element& left, const element& right)
{
    return left.value==right.value;
}
```

Примерно так.